# как юзать onMouseLeave

Tags: css, css3

Подскажите, хочу применить на сайте эффект обратный :hover/transition,когда убирается мышь из элемента, чтобы не происходило "бросания", а элемент плавно возвращался в исходное положение

Comment: А чем транзишн не устраивает?

Comment: он устраивает, когда наводить на элемент, а мне нужно при убирании мыши с него

Comment: Ну ты же когда наводишь, применяется правило для ховера, а когда убираешь, всё происходит в обратном порядке. Ща в сниппете покажу.

Comment: да, если можно, ибо у меня не применяется

Comment: `transition: all .3s ease;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот. Наводишь - плавно всё меняется. Уводишь - так же плавно, но в исходное положение. Зачем жс для таких вещей? Или я может не понял задачу.

```css
.a {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.a:hover {
  width: 220px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```